# Provably correct marshalling?

Tags: serialization, marshalling, formal-verification

Does there exist serialization schemes  (marshalling) of data structures that can be formally proven to be correct ?

I am agnostic to the particular programming language, could be ocaml/haskell or cpp, java or other as long as the data to be serialized can be assumed to be properly typed.

Perhaps as a way to reformulate/clarify my question what i am interested is whether there exists known standard encoding schemes to write data structures to disk which can proved to have 100% fidelity in the sense that the deserialized data is exactly the same as the original one.

As a simplifying assumption i can assume there is no complication of pointers/references. The input is “pure data” for a lack of a better way to say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a slightly vague question, but I'll have a go.

**Heterogenous Environments**

Serialisation's job is to take data in the memory of one computer program, convert it to some sort of standardised representation, and convert that back to  data in the memory of, quite possibly, another computer program on a completely different sort of computer. That does open up some interesting possiblities.

For example, the representation of a floating point value on many computers is IEEE754. But it's not wholly universal; historically companies like Cray and IBM used alternate formats, and so there exists the possibility that a value when deserialised on those machines might not be exactly the same value as was serialised in the first place. Generally no one cares, because the differences are numerically very small.

This shows up in some serialisation technologies; ASN.1's own wireformats for floats are either a text representation, or it's own binary format that is not IEEE754. The idea behind the text representation is that it can convey any floating point value, with no constraints. In contrast a binary format often has limits in the precision, maximum value, etc.

Text is another potential problem area; serialised unicode strings sent to another computer that doesn't support unicode will likely result in the deserialised string being different to the original.

Similarly with platforms that don't support 64bit integers, etc. Java is very annoying - historically it had no unsigned integers, so handling 64bit unsigned values received from, say, a C++ program is a nuisance.

**Conclusion - It's a Logical Impossibility**

So in some senses, for heterogenous environments, there can be no serialiatsion technologies formally proven to reproduce identical values because the destination machine is of a different architecture, and its representation may well be different, or limited in someway.

**Homogenous Environments**

Serialisation used to convey data from a computer program on one computer to exactly the same program on an identical computer (i.e. a homogenous environment) ought to produce exactly the same values on deserialisation. AFAIK there's no formally proven serialisation technologies. If there's serialisation built into the Ada language (I don't know) the Greenhills Ada compiler is formally proven. Boost for C++ is heavily peer reviewed, so that comes close, especially if used on top of Greenhill's formally proven C++ compiler, and has a serialisation library. Some of the commercial ASN.1 tools / libraries are very mature and highly trusted.

**What is it that is Formally Proven?**

In that last para I have touched on a difficulty with your question; formal proof is perhaps only of value if the entire software development stack (libraries, compiler, CPU) and you application source code are themselves formally proven. Otherwise you could have perfect source code for a serialisation library being compiled by a junk compiler, linked against rubbish libraries, running on a shonky CPU; it's not going to work.

So, when one is talking about "formally proven" one is generally talking about the whole system, not just an individual component. A component part that is, by itself, formally proven to meet its specification is a good aid to achieving a proven system, but it does not magically confer "correctness" on the whole system all on its own. Every other component needs to meet its specification too.

And what we've seen historically is that, quite often, CPUs don't really do what their data sheet says they do. Some will take shortcuts in floating point arithmetic in the interests of completing instructions in a single cycle in preference to achieving a numerically perfect result.

Sorry for the rambling answer, but I hope that's of interest and help.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to provide a readable and very informative answer to my vague question. I was having in mind a completely homogeneous environment in mind as simplifying assumption but i should have mentionned it. To be specific the environment here the rest of the environment here is all ocaml. You perfectly answered my question, however if you or someone is aware of results or example of robust serialisation libraries for ocaml (or haskell) i would be very interested to know!

Comment: @Ezy, no worries, you're welcome. I'm afraid I know nothing of ocaml or haskell. There are Google Protocol Buffers implementations for Haskell, and they're probably pretty good. GPB doesn't have size or value constraints though... There is an ASN.1 package (good), but it's version 0.0.1 (hmmm...).